# removing null values from an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

all I want to do is:

```
interface ApiParams {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string,
}
const params: ApiParams = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
const filtered: ApiParams = {};
Object.keys(params).forEach((key: keyof ApiParams) => {
  if (params[key] != undefined) {
    filtered[key] = params[key];
  }
})
```

But I get:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  filtered[key] = params[key];
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no hard constraint on maintaining your types the way they currently are, you could achieve the same using records.

I've rewritten your code using `Record<K, V>` below.

```
const params: Record<string, string> = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
const filtered: Record<string, string> = {};
Object.keys(params).forEach((key: string) => {
  if (params[key] != undefined) {
    filtered[key] = params[key];
  }
});
```